# Can't use canon mx435 scanner with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: canon, scanner

I installed the driver for the Canon printer, and it works OK with Ubuntu 13.04 but I can't use the scanner that comes with the printer. Any help?

Comment: Have you check out xsaned?

Comment: yes but no device available

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 (i386). By now, I could use printer and scanner. Canon Europe helps with manual for Linux. Look for driver and manual for scangear in Canon Europe Web. After decompressing package, install common and specific archives(.deb). Manual guides you how to do it with Gimp or in a console.

Where I did not get success was in Fax tools.